# Django Registration and Login on Same Index Page

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm trying to have a registration and login form both on my index page (NOT separate login/register urls). I'm able to display the forms, but having trouble with submission. At first I just had the registration form and submission for account creation worked just fine, but adding the Login form has started to cause some issues. Relatively new to Django and can't seem to find the documentation to fit my use case.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      if request.POST.get('submit') == 'login':
          login_form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
          username = request.POST.get('username')
          password = request.POST.get('password')
          user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
          if user:
              if user.is_active:
                  login(request,user)
                  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
              else:
                  return HttpResponse("Your account was inactive.")
          else:
              return HttpResponse("Invalid login details given")

      elif request.POST.get('submit') == 'register':
          form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
        login_form = AuthenticationForm()


    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    cur_year = now.year

    context = {
        'login_form': login_form,
        'form'  : form,
        'year'  : cur_year
    }

    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')
```

I get the following error on trying to submit either the login or register form:

```
local variable 'login_form' referenced before assignment
```

can provide website url if that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working through a combination of what @Chris Curvey answered and changing the buttons from using a value of 'login' or 'register' to a name with those strings, then in my conditions using "if 'login' in request.POST:"

```
if 'login' in request.POST:
    form = UserRegisterForm()
    [login logic]

elif 'register' in request.POST:
    login_form = AuthenticationForm()
    [registration logic]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the user submits an invalid registration form, you'll never define the login form.  Then when you hit `context =`, you will get this exception.

I'd suggest creating an "empty" form instance for the "other" form.  (That's hard to explain, an example will help

```
if request.POST.get('submit') == 'login':
    form = UserRegisterForm()
    login_form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)

    [login logic here]

elif request.POST.get('submit') == 'register':
    login_form = AuthenticationForm()
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)

    [registration logic here]
```